# Took over iPhone development on an app from another developer and getting code signing error

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I am able to get the software to build and run in the simulator and when I set it to device I get a code signing error as it has the previous developers code signature.  How do I get it to use my provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

Project > Edit Project Settings > Code Signing Identity